# Mysql: Problem using GREATEST with IFNULL and join

Tags: mysql, select

I have a query selecting the greatest value of 2 timestamps.

To achieve it I'm calling:

```
SELECT GREATEST( IFNULL( tableb.create_time, 0 ) , IFNULL( tablea.create_time, 0 ) )
```

I'm using `IFNULL` because the `create_time` value can be `null`.
The problem is that the result is something like '2014-0' instead of '2014-08-14 17:04:39'

Here's a [fiddle to illustrate my problem](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7729f/3)

The result is OK when:

- I'm not using `IFNULL`
- I'm using IFNULL but I have no join in the query (so the `GREATEST` is performed on 2 timestamps in the same table)

So for me the problem comes really from the use of `GREATEST` and `IFNULL` in a join query.

Comment: Use `TIMESTAMP'19700101'` instead of `0`.

Comment: Nice! Using COALESCE instead of IFNULL is also solving the issue.
I you want create an answer so I can mark it as solving my question!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    GREATEST
    (
        IFNULL(tableb.create_time,FROM_UNIXTIME(18000)),
        IFNULL(tablea.create_time,FROM_UNIXTIME(18000))
    );
```

It just so happens that `FROM_UNIXTIME(18000)` is `'1970-01-01 00:00:00'`

Comment: "It just so happens that `FROM_UNIXTIME(18000)` is `'1970-01-01 00:00:00'`" – doesn't it depend on `@@session.time_zone`? If you set it to `'+00:00'`, for instance, `FROM_UNIXTIME(18000)` will start evaluating to `'1970-01-01 05:00:00'`, no?